# Pixel to Vertex coordinate during off-screen rendering

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, metal

I'm drawing a set of triangles filled with plain color to off-screen texture.

My problem is that I get too big triangles in a result image, it looks like this:

[image]

My vertex coordinates are in pixels. (I simply generate them as a random float in (0, outTexture.width/height)). I do not multiply them by any projection in my vertex function (maybe that is my mistake?)

So my question is how does vertex coordinates correlate with pixel coordinate?

Comment: Its possible that your code is fine, and that the resultant image is larger than the top-level window.  Make sure the image view in which you present the result is fully contained by the window and that its content mode is UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

Comment: I open that image from finder, after exporting MTLTexture. I found out that that 32 point is half of my image which is 500 pixels. I dont understand that at all, that is very strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make ortho projection and pass it as a uniform.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
func makeOrthographicMatrix(left: Float, right: Float, bottom: Float, top: Float, near: Float, far: Float) -> [Float] {
    let ral = right + left
    let rsl = right - left
    let tab = top + bottom
    let tsb = top - bottom
    let fan = far + near
    let fsn = far - near

    return [2.0 / rsl,  0.0,        0.0,        0.0,
            0.0,        2.0 / tsb,  0.0,        0.0,
            0.0,        0.0,        -2.0 / fsn, 0.0,
            -ral / rsl, -tab / tsb, -fan / fsn, 1.0]
}
```

And I called that like so :

```
var projection = makeOrthographicMatrix(0.0, right: Float(inTexture.width), bottom: 0.0, top: Float(inTexture.height), near: -1.0, far: 1.0)
```